# RoR BlueCloth copy the html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bluecloth

Hello I am using for a rails (2.3.4) BlueCloth (2.0.11) an want type my text in die text box and after that I want to copy the html preview, which is provided by BlueCloth.

**Now**: when ever I mark the html, BlueCloth unmark it.
Can I FIX This?

[here a Screenshot](http://cl.ly/3n0v1R2o2I1N0j2U3k3v)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "mark the html" and "unmark it"? Do you want to use JavaScript to copy the HTML preview sent to the web browser, or are you just asking how to use Ruby to convert markdown into HTML as a string using Bluecloth?

Comment: **update**
I have to update the JavaScript because the JS is refreshing to fast and therefore I have to set the refreshing time lower.  
BUT THE JS FILE about 2000 Lines long?  
**CAN SOMEBODY HELP ME OUT**?

Comment: You need to supply a lot more details about your situation. Please edit your question to add information (and I will remove my downvote). As it is, you are assuming that people know how your code is set up and what "too fast" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a random guess: look for `setTimeout` or `setInterval` in your 2,000 lines of JavaScript. Either will have two parameters (the first of which may be a very long function literal), like so:

```
setTimeout( ..., xxx );
- or -
setInterval( ..., xxx );
```

The integer `xxx` is now long to wait, in milliseconds. Make it however long you want. At this point this question appears to have nothing to do with Ruby, Rails, or BlueCloth.

Comment: THANKS for the help
I have just increase the value of  `code
 setInterval(function() {
     var text = textarea.val();
     var html = converter.makeHtml(text);

     preview.html(html);
     htmlview.text(html);
 }, 10000);
    });`

Comment: @aetbaar_444 If this solved your problem then you should click the checkmark next to the answer to "accept" it. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Yeh I am from Germany and sorry for my bad english! :D  
AND the formatting